# Why can't Android emulator access WCF service on Android 10, but can on Android 9 or lower

Tags: android, wcf, xamarin, emulation

I'm running an Android emulator on Android 10 (API 29) and I had been developing on this for weeks now. I've done it before too no problems. This time, I shut my PC down over the weekend and when I started working on Monday morning, my emulator is unable to see/access our WCF service hosted on our private server.

I'm getting the following error when trying to access it through my app
`DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN`

I understand that means the domain is not available, but the question is why.

The  issue isn't even with the application, it's something generic with the emulator.
I can't even access it in the Google Chrome browser.

Any ideas?

I can make a fresh emulator running Android 10 and it will fail.
I can then make a fresh emulator running Android 9 or lower, and I am able to access the service fine.

Comment: is the problem accessing the service, or the server?  Have you tried using its IP instead of the domain?  Have you compared the DNS settings of the two different devices?

Comment: Its puzzling that it works on Android 9 but not 10, but it sounds like an issue with the DNS server. Since it used to work. Also, look at your server's error logs. Should see something different when Android 10 tries to connect. OR see that it isn't reaching server at all (nothing in log), which would confirm DNS server problem. Can also try pinging server. Or any means of asking server itself to respond (shouldn't be the WCS service itself, given that error message). Unless its related to the subdomain the WCS service is on.

Comment: @Jason accessing directly by IP works, but I need it to go through the DNS is the problem. I checked with network security and there was no updates or changes performed over the span of when it worked to when it did not work.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, there are the following reasons for **DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN**

1. The web browser cannot find the target website because the domain is not registered or has expired.
2. The domain does not point to any IP address.
3. There is a configuration error in the DNS settings of the user's computer, so the domain cannot be resolved.
4. VPN or antivirus software can interfere with network settings.
5. The problem comes from the internet provider.

Since you can run the emulator in Android 9 and it works fine, you can rule out server problems.

1. I think you can check if your Android 9 and Android 10 have the same DNS configuration. It is possible that its own DNS settings are causing this problem.

2.If your physical machine is connected to the wireless network through a LAN, your virtual machine will also read DNS through the LAN. But your previous Android 9 was working fine, which may not be the source of the problem. But here I still suggest you check it out.

3.Finally, the Android 10 upgrade also has related DNS updates, you can check the update documentation below.[Android 10 features and APIs](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/10/features)

Comment: The part I don't understand is what happened over the weekend from shutting my computer down, to turning it back on. Nothing was changed with my LAN, my computer/settings, or anything on the VPN/network related.

Comment: This is usually a problem on the client. The DNS cache was flushed due to a restart of the computer. I think you can try to modify the configuration of DNS manually. I don't think the difference in versions will cause this problem.